# Function sequence $ \left( \cos\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \right)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

I'm studying about uniform convergence of function sequences. I haven't been able to prove that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \cos\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \right)^n=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Hint: write $\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)^n=e^{n\ln\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}$, and calculate the limit of the exponent.

Comment: @velutluna I corrected a little mistake. Well, $\cos\left(x\right)\sim 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$, and $\ln\left(1-x\right)\sim -x$. I think that should work

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please try to make the title more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively $$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \left( \cos  \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)  \right) ^{ n }=exp\left( \lim _{ n\to \infty  } n\ln { \left( \cos  \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)  \right)  }  \right) =\\ =exp\left( \lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { \ln { \left( \cos  \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)  \right)  }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n }  }  \right) \overset { L'Hopital }{ = } exp\left( \lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { -\frac { \sin { \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)  }  }{ \cos  \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)  }  }{ -\frac { 1 }{ { n }^{ 2 } }  } \left( -\frac { x }{ 2n\sqrt { n }  }  \right)  \right) =\\ =exp\left( -\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \tan { \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)  } \frac { \sqrt { n }  }{ 2x } { x }^{ 2 } \right) ={ e }^{ -\frac{x^2}{2} }$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

For detailed proof, see this [Question about the proof of Central Limit Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757914/question-about-the-proof-of-central-limit-theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Compute the limit of the log, using *Taylor's formula* for the cosine at order $2$:
$$n\ln\Bigl(\cos\dfrac x{\sqrt n}\Bigr)=n\ln\biggl(1-\dfrac{x^2}{2n}+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\biggr)=n\biggl(-\dfrac{x^2}{2n}+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\biggr)=-\dfrac{x^2}2+o(1).$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem boils down to proving that
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} n\log\cos\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} = -\frac{x^2}{2}\tag{1} $$
and that can be achieved by squeezing. Both the functions $f(x)=\tan(x)$ and $g(x)=\frac{\tan x}{x}$ are convex on the interval $[0,1]$, hence it follows that
$$ \forall x\in[0,1],\qquad x\leq \tan(x) \leq x+x^3 \tag{2}$$
and by integrating those inequalities over the interval $[0,z]$, for some $z\in[0,1]$, we get:
$$ \forall z\in[0,1],\qquad \frac{z^2}{2}\leq -\log\cos(z) \leq \frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{4}\tag{3} $$
so by replacing $z$ with $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}}$ the claim follows by squeezing - for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the ratio $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}}$ belongs to the interval $[0,1]$ for any $n$ large enough.

Comment: Nice answer. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \cos\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \right)^n=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\sin^2\dfrac x{\sqrt n}\right)^{-1/\sin^2\frac x{\sqrt n}}\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-n\sin^2\frac x{\sqrt n}}2}$$

Now  setting $x/\sqrt n=h,$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{-n\sin^2\frac x{\sqrt n}}2=-\dfrac{x^2}2\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin^2h}{h^2}=?$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078615/find-lim-limits-x-to-0-frac-log-left-cos-x-rightx2-without-lhopita/2078623#2078623. We  can use $$1-\cos2A=2\sin^2A$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't understand why we can put the limit on the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Applying $\ln$ gives

$$\tag 1 n\cdot \frac{\ln \cos (x/\sqrt n)}{\cos (x/\sqrt n)-1}\cdot \frac{\cos (x/\sqrt n)-1}{(x/\sqrt n)^2}\cdot(x/\sqrt n)^2$$ $$= \frac{\ln \cos (x/\sqrt n)}{\cos (x/\sqrt n)-1}\cdot \frac{\cos (x/\sqrt n)-1}{(x/\sqrt n)^2}\cdot x^2.$$

Now let's use two well known limits

$$\tag 2\lim_{u\to 1} \frac{\ln u}{u-1} = 1,\,\,\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\cos u - 1}{u^2} = -\frac{1}{2}.$$

As $n\to \infty,$ $x/\sqrt n \to 0$ and $\cos (x/\sqrt n) \to 1,$ so the limits in $(2)$ show the limit of $(1)$ is $1\cdot (-1/2)\cdot x^2 = -x^2/2.$ Exponentiating back shows the original limit is $e^{-x^2/2}.$